# Can XGBoost do classification based on linear combinations?

Tags: classification, boosting, cart, multi-class

Suppose we have a data set $\mathcal{D}$ consisting of $n_C$ continuous features $\boldsymbol{X}_1, \boldsymbol{X}_2, \dots, \boldsymbol{X}_{n_C}$ and we wish to target a discrete variable $\boldsymbol{X}_D$ which takes 4 levels based on some linear combination of the continuous features. For simplicity, assume that $X_{i,D}$ is based on the value of $X_{i,1}+X_{i,2}$ (where $i$ refers to the $i$th observation) (e.g. if $X_{i,1}+X_{i,2} \in [a,b]$ then $X_{i,D} = 1$, if $X_{i,1}+X_{i,2} \in [c,d]$ then $X_{i,D} = 2$ etc. with $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ disjoint even, for simplicity). Would an XGBoost classifier be able to detect this relationship and build a classifier targeting $\boldsymbol{X}_D$ that uses all continuous features as predictors (obviously any other feature besides the 2 determining the relationship will be given an almost 0 importance)?

Comment: have you looked at lightgbm? https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#linear_tree. I believe XGBoost has plans to implement it

Comment: Haven't really come across that one before so thanks for the recommendation (will definitely look it up) but I'm mainly asking whether XGBoost would be able to discover a relationship such as the one described above. Can you maybe elaborate on why lightgbm would be expected to do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! XGBoost or any other gradient boosting machine implementation (LightGBM, CatBooost, etc.) would work fine. Approximating, a purely linear function by recursively partitioning our sample space using tree-based learners can require training a large number of base learners (i.e. doing a lot of "iterations") but aside from that it is nothing "too exotic".
seanv507's suggestion with [LightGBM 's linear treee base learner](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#linear_tree) will likely require fewer iterations (i.e. using a smaller number of base learners)  as we will have a model at each leaf that is linear instead of constant (i.e. it should capture that linear dependency more naturally/efficiently). Finally, to state the obvious, maybe using a different learning methodology (e.g. Elastic Net) might be more suitable if have known linear patterns dominating our underlaying data-generating mechanism.

Comment: How about setting `booster = "gblinear"` in XGBoost? Isn't that the same as going for LightGBM's linear tree base learner (of course using XGBoost instead of LightGBM)?

Comment: No it is not the same. It is actually a "simple" ElasticNet model in that case that we learn with successively small updates; `lineartree ` is akin to the M5 tree model. (which never really took off)